# Get usable array from a curl response, which is formatted as a php array

Tags: php, arrays, curl, multidimensional-array

```
$ch = curl_init("url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "test"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$outputArray = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then $outputArray will contain:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [r1] => test response
        [r2] => 4
        [r3] => 32
    )

)
```

So I would think PHP can see that it's an array and treat it as such, but when I do something like

```
echo $outputCode[0][r_title]."\n";
```

it gives an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use string offset as an array in /www/test.php on line 75
```

(line 75 being the echo one just above)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you are getting is probably not an array, but a string containing an array structure, e.g. output by `print_r()`. This kind of data will *not* automatically be converted back into a PHP array.

If you can control the page you are querying this from, encode the data using a method like [serialize()](http://www.php.net/serialize) or [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/json_encode) and on the querying side, decode the data you get from curl using ([unserialize()](http://www.php.net/unserialize) or [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/json_decode)) respectively. Those functions will give you a proper PHP array.

If you have no way to change the way the URL outputs its data, the only way I can see is (yuck!) using [eval()](http://www.php.net/eval) - I can elaborate on that if need be, but it's a really really bad idea.

Comment: Ok, yeah I change the page I'm querying :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$outputArray` is **a string**, that seems to contain something like the ouput of `print_r()`.

There is no way PHP can *guess* that string represents an array -- and it's not really close to the syntax that's used to declare an array ; so this will not work.

A solution would be :

- to modify the remote script you're calling, so it returns a string containing some serialized data

  - i.e. and array, serialized with `serialize`
  - or with `json_encode`
- And, on your side, unserialize the data, to get the array back,

  - with either `unserialize`
  - or `json_decode`

Comment: If we've got great minds *(well, that would be good news, wouldn't it ? )*, then, yes they do ;-)

Comment: I would of given you both a "tick" as both answers are equally right, but sadly I couldn't.

Comment: Boah, don't worry about that :-) What matters is that you got an (well, two ^^ ) answer(s).